# Wordpress React Plugin Routing Conflict with Rewrite

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, routes

Hello I am building a custom React app that I tie into a custom page template in Wordpress via a shortcode.

My issue I believe is that Wordpress's rewrite rules conflict with the app when I attempt to open a new tab and navigate based on URL. The full URL doesn't route correctly.

It's something or other like this I think... not exactly you know but I think close

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^options/quote-chain/([^/]+)/calls/([^/]+)$ /blank-page.php?p=873custom_var1=$matches[1]&custom_var2=$matches[2] [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^options/quote-chain/([^/]+)/puts/([^/]+)$ /blank-page.php?p=873custom_var1=$matches[1]&custom_var2=$matches[2] [QSA,L]
```

functions.php

```
function wealth_compass_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^options/quote-chain/([^/]+)/calls/([^/]+)$', 'blank-page.php?p=873custom_var1=$matches[1]&custom_var2=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^options/quote-chain/([^/]+)/puts/([^/]+)$', 'blank-page.php?p=873custom_var1=$matches[1]&custom_var2=$matches[2]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'wealth_compass_rewrite_rules');
```

Currently it reroutes to the app on the custom template page but the URL is consumed and it goes to the base url instead of the full route. In testing with React alone it routes correctly. Before fiddling some with it, it would say Wordpress cannot find the page yada yada.

Comment: So _where_ exactly did you put those lines? Before the general WP rewrites ...?

Comment: (And what is with those double `^^` at the beginning of your patterns?)

Comment: @CBroe in htaccess and function php both are at the end after the other rewrites and such. Also I double checked and actually there is no double ^^ this was a copy paste from chatgpt but I had actually corrected it in the htaccess file. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: "are at the end after the other rewrites" -- That is probably your problem.  The default rewrite for wordpress comes first and has the `[L]` flag, so yours never gits triggered.  Try putting your rewrite in .htaccess first.